# Starting library activity from android application

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest, implicit

Hi I am doing some experiments in which I have one sample library project which contains one sample activity. I have included that library project inside my main project. Now I want to start that sample activity inside my library project from my main project. I tried this is in following ways but it is giving error `class not found error` :

```
// my library manifest file... No activity define inside it...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidvideoapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

</application>

</manifest>
```

following is main project manifest.

```
// inside main project manifest...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidvideoapp2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.androidvideoapp.MainActivity" // this is my library activity...
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.example.androidvideoapp2.AddVideoActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>        
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

And I am trying to open this activity in following way...

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.androidvideoapp2.AddVideoActivity"));
```

But it is giving following error

```
11-29 15:13:26.404: E/AndroidRuntime(14428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 15:13:26.404: E/AndroidRuntime(14428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to        instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.androidvideoapp2/com.example.androidvideoapp.MainActivity}: 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.androidvideoapp.MainActivity
```

Am I doing anything wrong. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: did you include the library inside project Properties/android?

Comment: @Arash I have included that library project inside properties/Android. But still same result.

Comment: @DerGolem : no it not a requirement, i have library project activities with just defining them in Main Project(not in Library manifest), and its working

Comment: @Ger Golem I have tried that as well. But same result. Any other option. I am not sure whether I am doing it in right way or not. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: can you try starting your Activity explicitly(without an action, by its class name) ?

Comment: But that class is not present inside my project then how to specify explicitly that class. I am not sure about it. Will try and let you know.

Comment: if you are properly include that library inside your main Project , so you can see that library class inside your Main Project code!

Comment: Try using `new Intent(context, AddVideoActivity.class)` instead to make sure the project is imported and the class path is correct. Then, debug more.

Comment: OK let me try and and will get back to you guys.

Comment: yeah guys I tried this Its working without any error but it is not launching or not showing any UI. I tried with class name.Its going inside library activity oncreate method but no UI displayed. Dont know why?

Comment: It is actually launching that activity but not showing any UI. It goes through onresume and onpause or oncreate everything. But not showing on any activity UI.